# Reporting Previous Records on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I’m struggling a bit here.  The data is fabricated, but the query concept is very real.
I need to select the Customer, Current Amount, Previous Amount, Sequence and Date
WHERE DATE < 1190105
AND the DATE/SEQ is the maximum date/seq prior to that date point grouping by customer.

I’ve spent quite a few days trying all sorts of things using HAVING, nested select to try and obtain the max-date/amount and min-date/amount by customer and can’t quite get my head around it.  I’m sure it should be quite easy, but any help you can offer would be really appreciated.

Thanks

```
**SEQ       DATE        CUSTOMER    AMOUNT**
1           1181225     Bob         400
2           1181226     Fred        300
3           1190101     Bob         100
4           1190104     Fred        500
5           1190104     George      200
6           1190105     Bob         150
7           1190106     Bob         200
8           1190110     Fred        160
9           1190110     Bob         300
10          1190112     Fred        400
```

Comment: Sample output would help.

Comment: `LAG`/`LEAD`..?

Comment: Something is odd with your logic. You want a record that has a date higher than 1190101 and also the date has to be prior to that date by customer?

Comment: Oops.  I meant less than!  Sorry.

Comment: Lag sounded a good solution but alas I'm working in SQL 2005 (don't ask!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opt 1 use row number and lag functions

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By CustomerID Order By [Date]) as Sec,
    [Date],
    Customer,
    Amount as CurrentAmount,
    Lead(Amount) OVER (Partition By CustomerID, Order By [Date]) as PreviousAmount
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    [DATE] < 1190105
```

Opt use outer apply

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Customer Order By [Date]) as Sec,
    [Date],
    Customer,
    Amount as CurrentAmount,
    Prev.Amount  as PreviousAmount
FROM
    YourTable T
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM YourTable 
    WHERE Customer = T.Customer AND [Date] < T.[Date]
    ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
) Prev
WHERE
   DATE < 1190105
```

Opt 3 use a correlated subquery

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By Customer Order By [Date]) as Sec,
    [Date],
    Customer,
    Amount as CurrentAmount,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM YourTable 
        WHERE Customer = T.Customer AND [Date] < T.[Date]
        ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
    )  as PreviousAmount
FROM YourTable
WHERE
    DATE < 1190105
```

Answer (score 0):

First restrict the rows with the date filter, then search for the max by customer.

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
DECLARE @FilterDate INT = 1190105

;WITH MaxDateByCustomer AS
(
    SELECT
        T.CUSTOMER,
        MaxSEQ = MAX(T.SEQ)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    WHERE
        T.Date < @FilterDate
    GROUP BY
        T.CUSTOMER
)
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    YourTable AS T
    INNER JOIN MaxDateByCustomer AS M ON 
        T.CUSTOMER = M.CUSTOMER AND
        T.SEQ = M.MaxSEQ
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
DECLARE @FilterDate INT = 1190105

;WITH DateRankingByCustomer AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        DateRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.CUSTOMER ORDER BY T.SEQ DESC)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    WHERE
        T.Date < @FilterDate
)
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
    DateRankingByCustomer AS D
WHERE
    D.DateRanking = 1
```